# Azure Powershell agent task pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm just wondering whats the chain underlies `Azure Powershell VSO agent task`. I assume that is not simple powershell host because it is not working with some commandlets (for example `Get-Module -ListAvailable`) and fails with an error:

> The term 'Get-ServiceEndpoint' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again.
>
> A Connected Service with name 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx' could not be found.  Ensure that
> this Connected Service was successfully provisioned using services tab
> in Admin UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTS build task are normal powershell scripts. However the 'Get-ServiceEndpoint' is a known issue: [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/1112).

As far as I can see other cmdlets are working normally. I've been able to write several build tasks without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.